# Problems with adding javascript in html with jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

beginning beginner here, I wrote a little and simple text based adventure in javascript, which asks the choices of the guy running the thing in jsfiddle. Now I want to add images, and text to that with html. The problem being that I dont know how to add the things step by step. I dont want the whole adventure being written all at once, I want it to be written step by step. Everything that existed in the confirm("") form should be going in a text form in html, and the prompts should not be written down. Adressing this issue is the most important, images and such are way less important.

Comment: A link would be important to help you. And a specific problem should be asked in here. You should check [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Martinpecher/106cym0L/14/ (keep answering no to get out of the script) kinda the script, and : http://jsfiddle.net/Martinpecher/6y72sy0w/  what I'm trying. In the if/else, there are confirms, that I'd want to be paragraphs in the html section. I don't think I'm being quite clear, hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you asking how to add text and images in HTML?  Any introductory HTML tutorial would cover that.  `img` tags are useful for images, and text can go just about anywhere.

Comment: I think I've understood how to add text/img or make links, I'm having difficulty getting the html and the javascript together, and play step by step.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your "story" should have a graphical user interface in the web page. That means you should create some **html** markup that makes the story flow along with an animation. This is not an easy task and a great ability in javascript and libraries like *jQuery* or *AngularJS* (just a couple of examples) is required. Such a project shouldn't use dialog boxes caled **"alerts"** from your browser.
As a beginner(you said you are a beginner), I advise you to take it easy and start with a less pain-in-the-ass web project.

A few tutorials and platforms where you can try to learn the skills needed are:

- [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/projects)
- [Learn Angular](http://www.learn-angular.org/)
- [Toptal: Guide for your first AngularJS app](http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/a-step-by-step-guide-to-your-first-angularjs-app)

And a website with a great User Interaction is [Quiz App](https://polymer-topeka.appspot.com/).